# validation in struts2

Tags: validation, struts2

```
public class Admin extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<AdminData>
  {
   AdminData adminData = new AdminData();
   public AdminData getModel()
     {
        return adminData;
    }


   @Validations(requiredStrings ={
      @RequiredStringValidator(type=ValidatorType.FIELD,fieldName="emailId"),
    @RequiredStringValidator(type=ValidatorType.FIELD,fieldName="password")}
    public String auth()
    {
     }


     @Validations(requiredStrings ={
     @RequiredStringValidator(type=ValidatorType.FIELD,fieldName="emailId"),
        @RequiredStringValidator(type=ValidatorType.FIELD,fieldName="firstName"),
        @RequiredStringValidator(type=ValidatorType.FIELD,fieldName="surName"),
        @RequiredStringValidator(type=ValidatorType.FIELD,fieldName="password")}
   public String create() throws DatabaseException
   {

    }

}
```

my problem is that when i call `create()` method there is no problem in validation, but when i call `auth()` method there is problem with validation because when i call auth method it is goes for validation of firstname and surname.

and there is all getset in AdminData.java

Comment: What do you see when you submit your from? And post you JSP.

Comment: When my action call auth() method its do validation of create() means do validation not only for email and password its also do validation for email firstname surname and password

Comment: Show your JSP and action configuration.

Answer (score 0):

By default Struts2 validator will check all validation constraints from all methods. You can configure struts to look only for validation constraints related to current method. Just turn on `validateAnnotatedMethodOnly` in your `struts.xml`:

```
<struts>
    <package ...>
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">

                .....

                <!-- Turning per method validation on -->
                <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                    <param name="validateAnnotatedMethodOnly">true</param>
                    <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
                </interceptor-ref>

                ......

            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>
    </package>
</struts>
```

See corresponding documentation entry: [Different validations per method](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/validations-annotation.html#ValidationsAnnotation-Differentvalidationspermethod)